# Error when calling blogdown::build_site on Unix, command fails

Tags: rstudio, r-markdown, blogdown

I am using:

- R 3.5.2
- Blogdown (latest from CRAN)
- Unix CentOS (Docker) on Windows host

#### Problem

I am trying to build a site in Blogdown. The site I am trying to build is [Hugo XMin](https://github.com/yihui/hugo-xmin) as it is with no modifications. I have:

1. Cloned the repository of the Hugo XMin site in my Unix system.
2. Installed all dependencies on Unix.
3. Ran command `blogdown::build_site()` inside the site root folder after entering R in interactive mode in Bash by just using command `R`.

The error I get is the following:

```
> blogdown::build_site()
Rendering content/_index.Rmarkdown
running: bash  -c "cd ../..;
find . -not -path '*/exampleSite/*' \\( -name '*.html' -o -name '*.css' \\) | xargs wc -l"
pandoc: Error running filter pandoc-citeproc
pandoc-citeproc not found in path
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted
Warning message:
In file.remove(intermediate_html) :
  cannot remove file '_index.tmp.html', reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in render_page(f) : Failed to render 'content/_index.Rmarkdown'
```

On my Windows machine, this works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I was tricked by the message and did not see that `pandoc-citeproc` is been required but not found. So the fix is easy:

```
yum install pandoc-citeproc
```